# How to use trigger KEY-ENTER in Text Field Multiple Line Oracle Forms

Tags: oracle, forms, oracle10g, oracleforms

1./ Could I ask about Oracle Forms,
I have a Text Field with Multiple lines in Oracle Forms,
when I input the value and click Enter then will move the new line inside the text box,
But I want to click Enter then will move to the Next Item in the forms

I used trigger event KEY-ENTER but it did not work as expected

```
GO_ITEM('XXXBLOCK.QUANTITY');
```

2./ Or you can help me with how to use the TextBox Field which can copy and paste with the list value below

```
A20230101001
A20230101002
A20230101003
A20230101004
```

If we use Textbox Field with single-line then we just have only the value A20230101001 copied

Thanks,

Comment: removed "oracle-apex" and "oracle-sqldeveloper" tags since this question is unrelated to those products

Answer (score 0):

By default, "Multi line" property is set to "No" which means that item is "single line".

Online Forms documentation states:

> **Single-line**: Pressing the carriage return key while the input focus is in a single-line text item initiates a [Next Item] function.
>
> **Multi-line**: Pressing the carriage return key while the input focus is in a multi-line text item **starts a new line in the item**.

Therefore, you can't do it with `KEY-ENTER` trigger.

---

Workaround? Certainly; press **TAB** key; it'll set focus to the next item. If *quantity* is the one, good. Otherwise, create a `KEY-NEXT-ITEM` trigger and put

```
GO_ITEM ('XXXBLOCK.QUANTITY');
```

in there.

Comment: The scanner tool will press Enter not TAB. So that is why I need a trigger KEY-ENTER

Comment: Or you can help me with how to use the TextBox Field which can copy and paste with the list value below

A20230101001
A20230101002
A20230101003
A20230101004

If we use Textbox Field with single-line then we just have only the value A20230101001 copied

Comment: When I had to do something similar - by reading barcode with a scanner - I had delimiter (# character, as it didn't appear anywhere in scanned text) so I just split that "long" string I read into pieces and put each of them into its **separate** form field. Perhaps you could do the same - split it on CHR(10) and/or CHR(13) (line feed / carriage return).

Comment: The split string is ok, but the scanner after the split will press Enter, which we need that the cursor will move to the next text-box item in the Forms.

Answer (score 0):

Trigger KEY-ENTER is forms action trigger like any other (KEY-ENTQRY, KEY-EXIT, KEY-COMMIT....) - it is not connected to any kind of keystroke listener as you are trying to use it. So, it looks like you are asking for event trigger that doesn't exist. It would be nice to have the oportunity to use WHEN-KEY-PRESSED trigger in forms. Unfortunately there is no such trigger.
There is a way (using Java Bean) that allows sending back to the Forms application each key pressed in any Text Item. Never tryed it myself, but it is described at: http://forms-pjc-bean.over-blog.com/article-15980196.html - maybe there you could find the solution to do what you need.